# How can I sort list of custom object by multiple properties of objects

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nsdate

Can someone help me to sort list of my custom objects by multiple parameters.
I want to sort it by date1 and date2 and optionally b all three properties but whatever I try it fails :( 
My object:

```
class MyObject : NSManagedObject{
   @NSManaged var date1:NSDate
   @NSManaged var date2:NSDate
   @NSManaged var key:Int
}
```

This is my failed tries to sort list of those objects:

```
var sortedArray1 = sorted(unorderedList, { (o1: MyObject, o2: MyObject) -> Bool in{
            return o1.date1 == o2.date1 ? (o1.date2 < o2.date2) : (o1.date1 < o2.date1)
        }

        var sortedArray2 = sorted(unorderedList, { (o1: MyObject, o2: MyObject) -> Bool in
            return (o1.date1.compare(o2.date1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending) == (o1.date1.compare(o2.date1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending) ? (o1.date2.compare(o2.date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending) : (o1.date1.compare(o2.date1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending))
        });
```

Comment: Could you please specify in details the criteria for sorting.

Comment: `date1` and `date2` are date with time. This is some from and to properties. I need to sort list by those two properties to get something like like: `04:00to05:00, 04:00to05:30` etc. And `key` is simple `1,2,3...` but that key can also be `nil` so primary sorting should be by `date` properties.

Comment: So sort by date and if dates are equal get into account the keys. For dates you could not use < or > operators as these are not provided by Swift except you have defined it yourself. Same for == or != operators. If you have not and wants to do it, I will request you to look at this framework https://github.com/abdullah-chhatra/iDate.

Comment: Ok if I want to avoid sorting by `key` so just by dates how can I sort this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out and let me know:

```
unorderedList.sorted({
    if $0.date1 < $1.date1 {
        return true
    } else if $0.date1 == $date2 {
        return $0.date2 < $1.date2
    }
    return false
})

public func == (left: NSDate, right: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return left.isEqualToDate(right)
}

public func != (left: NSDate, right: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return !left.isEqualToDate(right)
}

public func > (left: NSDate, right: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return left.compare(right) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
}

public func < (left: NSDate, right: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return left.compare(right) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
```

Comment: I get: `NSDate is not a subtype of NSString`. Where should I put those functions?

Comment: Put those in any file of your project outside of any class.

Comment: Results are wrong: 01:00to04:00, 02:00to04:00, 01:00to04:00, 01:00to04:00, 03:00to04:00

Comment: Try the new code. You could try to manipulate the conditions to make it work for you.